# Search bar for android app

Tags: android, google-maps, searchbar

I'm creating an android app with google maps functionality, I want the end result to look just like the google maps app, I have the map working with the navigation drawer, but I'm stuck at the search bar, I want it to be just like the search bar in the official app but I don't know where to start, is that search bar a fragment? An action bar? What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler than you might think, using [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget).

Shout if you get stuck.

Comment: so it's basically a toolbar with autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, and the autocomplete uses the Google Places API, meaning it proposes addresses, places, businesses... Just like the search box in Google Maps.

Comment: As that page explains, you can also provide your own ui and get the place predictions programmatically - should the basic widget not suit your needs.